# Implementation of payment gateway for credit card in android

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment

I am wanted to add payment gateway in my android app for purchasing certain thing and allow after payment is done.

now problem is that i have read some where that some payment gateway does not supported by google play they are rejecting that app.

can any one tell me proper payment gateway i can implement in my app which is allowed by google play.

is there any such thing provided by google self too ?

please let me know

thanks
Yagnesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is, it's called **Google Play In-app Billing**.

In-app Billing is a Google Play service that lets you sell digital content from inside your applications. You can use the service to sell a wide range of content, including downloadable content such as media files or photos, virtual content such as game levels or potions, premium services and features, and more. You can use In-app Billing to sell products as

- Standard in-app products (one-time billing), or
- Subscriptions, (recurring, automated billing)

See [Google Play In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)